# Unclickable link inside div

Tags: html, css, wordpress

I have added a custom button [Upload CV] to my WP theme right above the main menu, next to the social media icons, I have also added a link to it and I am testing it at the moment, but it seems the link  is not working, I'm not sure why... I just need a second opinion maybe there's something I've missed.

I have already tried looking through questions already answered about this issue, but I cannot seem to find where my issue is coming from.

Here is the website http://callidus.o2clite.com/

Thank you for your help.

Comment: It gets overflowed by the .col-md-6 container. Try putting it inside it.

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**.   Although you have provided a link to an example, if the link were to become invalid, your question would be of no value to other future SO users with the same problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The button is overflowed by the .col-md-6 container, you can do this

**CSS**

```
#uploadcv-btn {
  background-color: #ad004a;
  float: right;
  font-size: 16px !important;
  margin-right: 8%;
  padding: 5px 27px;
  position: relative;
  top: -28px;
}
```